# One way sync SQL Server Data based on value of specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-ec2, ssis

I need to sync/push data from one SQL server (owned by our CRM) to our own SQL server (on AWS RDS) for reporting and analysis. There are 3 tables and I believe there is a column for owner/id which determines if the data in that row belongs to us. (They have data from multiple different companies in the same tables)

I can use SSIS to import the initial data set when they manually dump our data but is there a way to setup a limited remote connection(only allows us to access the rows which we are the owner) so that we can automatically pull in the new data to our reporting server each night?

Comment: You'll need to talk to whoever owns the server.  Yes it is possible but they may well prefer to push the data to you.

Comment: That would be easier for me, I just don't know if they know how to provide access to only the rows of data that we own.

Comment: SQL Server 2014, and above, supports [row level security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx). Or they can expose just your rows using a view. But personally I won't want an external company connecting directly. I'd prefer to push the data, on a fixed schedule, via SSIS. In any case you'll need to talk to the server owners.